# jQuery .ajax GET from application/atom+xml works in Chrome but not IE

Tags: rest, jquery, excel, ajax

I'm trying to build a dynamic table in SP 2010 using the ExcelRest API and jQuery $.ajax. It works like a charm in Chrome but fails in IE.

The relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://ohc/cdc/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/SiteAssets/pm/schedule/project_schedule_data.xlsx/model/Ranges('project_schedule')?$format=atom",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: "false",
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            $('row', data).each(function() {
                // IE never gets here
                $('<tr></tr>').appendTo('.wbs_table tbody');
                $('c', this).each(function() {
                    $('<td></td>').text($('fv', this).text()).appendTo('.wbs_table tbody tr:last-child');
                });
            });

            cleanupTable();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, statusText) {
            alert(status + ': ' + statusText);
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            // had been debugging here
        }
    });
});
```

Might be worthwhile to add that this is an intranet site? So far I've confirmed that IE receives the XML document, and that the XHR responseText is the complete/correct XML string.

I've tried all the things I could find about taking the XML string and converting it into an MS XMLDOC. Using $.parseXML(data) has no effect on the behavior because IE already sees it as an XML document, and I can find all the information by navigating through the console. It's like the jQuery selectors aren't working.

Before using selectors I was using .find() with the exact same results.

```
$(data).find('row').each(function() {...});
```

I switched to the selector approach because I thought the problem might have been with .find().

This is driving me completely insane. I feel like the problem is probably due to the MIME type that ExcelRest.aspx returns?